# Appropriate amount of error checking in low level systems

Tags: c, embedded, hardware

I was interviewing with a measurement and test company for a low level role, and the interviewer asked if this code was valid:

```
void changeValue(int *a, int size){
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        a[i] = i;
   }

}
```

But apparently this is more correct:

```c
void changeValue(int *a, int size){
  if(a){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        a[i] = i;
    }
  }
}
```

I know you are supposed to check if `malloc()` returns the null pointer, but this seems very defensive.  I have only taken a few low level classes at SJSU though.  Is this type of stack error checking common in embedded systems?  Is there "master list" of error checks a junior programmer should know?

Comment: There's no `malloc()` in this function, so it's probably not the right place for the check. You could pass an array with static or automatic duration to this function, which would make the "check" pointless. More to the point, there are many, many more bad values a pointer can have than `NULL`, and this code won't catch any of them. Suppose you pass a pointer to this function after sending it to `free()`, for instance, or after incrementing it further than you should.

Comment: I knew it!  I was surprised when he said this type of checking was useful.  Maybe he was just trying to direct me to the incorrect path so he could check my assertive nature.

Comment: To some extent, it depends on the context in which the code is written. If this is a library function that is called by other programmers, maybe it should check the pointer, but it is hard to check it thoroughly. Maybe an `assert(a != 0);` (or `assert(a);`) is appropriate instead of, or as well as, the `if` check. If the function is internal to the library, it is more reasonable to document that "this function must be called with a non-null pointer". It isn't clear that doing nothing and not letting the user know is a good strategy. OTOH, it isn't clear what would be a better strategy, either.

Comment: Conversely, this type of construct may be more legitimate when you expressly *can* pass `NULL` to the function, in the same way that you can pass `NULL` to `free()` and have it do nothing. It's not beyond possibility that you could have a situation where you might want to set some elements to `NULL`, and still be able to pass them all safely to this function, although admittedly I'm struggling to think of an example, particularly when you have to pass the size, too. But even then, this wouldn't really be about "safety" as much as it would be about making the function more flexible.

Comment: your code works correctly.  The check of 'a' that was added is only for checking that an actual value was passed as a pointer to 'a'.  This is common when the code is not deterministic.  However, when the parameter 'a' is 'always' a valid value, this is not necessary.  However, even if 'a' pointer is not null, does not mean that it is a valid pointer, so the extra check (in this instance) is worthless.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : `malloc` is not the only possible source of NULL pointer.  In fact amongst the less likely.

Comment: @TringVu : You "knew it" because someone on the Internet agreed with you!?  You truly have much to learn! ;-)

Comment: @Clifford: That's a direct response to the statement in the original question, "I know you are supposed to check if `malloc()` returns the null pointer".

Comment: @PaulGriffiths :  I appreciate that, but it does make this the "wrong place" for a null pointer check, only the wrong place for a memory allocation failure check.  A statically allocated pointer that was never assigned a value for example will be null, so it is to trap other errors.  Moreover your comments look a lot like an answer, and you could have perhaps posted one.  I don't think an inability to trap all kinds of error is a strong argument on its own for checking for none.

Comment: @Clifford: "it does make this the 'wrong place' for a ... memory allocation failure check" - I believe that's exactly what I said, viz. "the" check, rather than "a" check. Fair point on the comment vs answer thing. I agree with your last comment, although I do think an inability to trap all potentially bad values except a single one *is* a strong argument against describing the code under consideration as "more correct", which was the point in the original question, particularly when you consider Jonathan's point that doing nothing in response may bring its own problems.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : I was reiterating the part that we perhaps agree on, my point was that the *same test* is used to check for a *different error*.  And I do believe the interviewer's argument is weak and it is a poor interview question (at least as reported by Tring).  The arguments are covered in my answer and that of others - best not to clutter the comments with this discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is valid, but inherently unsafe, even after the suggested improvement.

- `if (a)` will catch a null pointer, but there are many other bad values a pointer could have.
- the pointer could be a dangling pointer - pointer to memory previously sent to `free()`.
- there's no way to tell if `a` points to an array that actually has `size` number of elements.

It is more likely the interviewer was hoping for you to raise these several issues.

Comment: Also, the function doesn't return any values to indicate that an error was caught in the first place!  Imagine continued use of this array after this function fails.

Answer (score 3):

Everything @CAB says is correct, but here's a different viewpoint:

1. Whatever code directly calls `malloc` must check the validity of the allocation unless you have a system-wide trap for unsuccessful allocation calls, such as if you happen to be in C++-land and have an exception handler at the top level of code that tells users things have gone very badly and the application will now be failing.
2. NULL (a NULL pointer) is a common and meaningful pointer value.  This may *not* be a result of a failed allocation (point #1), but could represent an object that's been deleted, not yet allocated, or a reference that hasn't yet been updated.  In this case, checking that the pointer is non-NULL is reasonable, if not fully necessary.  Experience tells me that this sort of error trapping is a good idea in practice, when you're not in control of the calling code.  There's still an intermittent bug in a major company's code because empty values are being sometimes passed to code I wrote.
3. It is *not* the responsibility of the receiving code to check for "validity" of the input values, including that the pointer refers to actual memory.  For one thing, most systems don't have the capability to do that.  For another, something has already gone very wrong within the system, perhaps unrecoverably, if there are non-NULL invalid pointers being passed around.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question "is it valid" is patently "yes", if it compiles it is valid.  Perhaps "is it safe" is a better question, but C is intrinsically unsafe and easily abused and misused in ways that will cause a system to fail.

Checking the validity of input parameters is perhaps not unusual, but for low-level "leaf" functions, a system will often end up performing the same validity check on the same quantity multiple times to no useful effect.

The problem with this function is that if `a` is NULL the function will fail, but that is only one failure mode - there are others that you cannot so easily protect against. It is already the responsibility of the caller to ensure the input is a valid pointer and that size is appropriately assigned, so having this function check for NULL provides minimal protection at perhaps considerable cost is similar checks are used throughout the code.

All that said, on a project with multiple developers with varying experience and competency, it is perhaps not a given that the pointer will be valid or previously checked.  Moreover, if the code in question is library code to be reused amongst multiple projects, this kind of fastidious checking may be useful.

In this case the suggested solution is seriously flawed; it detects a bug, but does nothing about it - it does not even return an indication of the problem.  It simply returns having done nothing, leaving some other code to fail or perform the same check.

In this case, as an interviewer I would have given greater credit had you suggested the following:

```
int changeValue(int *a, int size)
{
    assert( a != 0 ) ;

    int i = 0 ;
    if( a != 0 )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            a[i] = i;
        }
    }
    return i ;
}
```

In this case the *pre-condition* that `a` is not NULL is tested by an assertion.  The standard assert macro is only defined when NDEBUG is *not* defined, so that the checking is only done in debug builds, leaving tested release code free from the unnecessary overhead.  When NDEBUG is undefined, the assert will cause an appropriate handler to be called; in an embedded system this is typically an indefinite loop or a forced breakpoint, so that the system may be interrupted in a debugger and the call-stack or trace data inspected to determine where the fault occurred.

When the NDEBUG is defined, the assert has no effect, but the function nonetheless returns a value that indicate its success (it will return 0 on failure of `size` on success).  You can avoid the double testing of `a` in debug by rearranging the function as follows:

```
int changeValue(int *a, int size)
{
    int i = 0 ;
    if( a == 0 )
    {
        assert( false ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        for( i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            a[i] = i;
        }
    }

    return i ;
}
```

You should certainly avoid the assumption that a pointer refers only to data provided by `malloc()` - that is certainly not the case, indirection has many uses, and the pointer passed may not have been a malloc pointer, so simply checking malloc return is insufficient.

In the end there is a development policy question to be asked;  do you error check for conditions that can occur in correct code, or do you check for actual bugs?  Library code including checks for correct usage is valid - because it will be used and reused in many different situations perhaps not envisaged by the original developer, though I am not sure you interviewers example is a particularly convincing case.  Application specific code on the other hand should be exhaustively tested in any case, and checking for coding errors rather than plausible system conditions is less useful.